# WP7 listbox get item in the viewport (similar to agenda in calendar)

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I am trying to mimic the listbox in "agenda" in WP7 Calendar. If you scroll through the listbox, the date keeps changing on the top.

So, is there a way to identify what item the user is looking in the listbox?